# Mocha not exiting

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm running into an issue where Mocha is not exiting.

I read that it can be because I have dangling resources, but I'm not sure where.

My code is:

```js
import express from 'express';

let app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Done');
});

app.listen(3000);

export default app;
```

And my test is:

```js
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import app from '../app';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Simple test', () => {
    it('Should', async () => {
        let response = await chai.request(app).get('/');
        expect(response).to.have.status(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `app.listen(3000)` is blocking the process from exiting.

Import the `app` object without calling `app.listen(3000)` when running your tests.

### `app.js`

```
import express from 'express';

let app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end('Done');
});


export default app;
```

### `test.js`

```
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import app from './app';

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Simple test', () => {
  it('Should', async () => {
    let response = await chai.request(app).get('/');
    chai.expect(response).to.have.status(200);
  });
});
```

In another module import `app` and start it listening to run your server as normal.

### `main.js`

```
import app from './app'

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize that.

Answer (score 3):

Try running your test with the `--exit` flag. This will "Force Mocha to quit after tests complete" [ref](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage)

`$ mocha --exit ./test.test.js`